# Powershell script that updates Active Directory user information

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wrote this Powershell script years ago for updating AD from a CSV file.  I'd like to try to optimize to run quicker and be more efficient... but I'm not sure where to start / what could improve it.  Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: I've updated my original script to this:

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Employees.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {

$employeeNumber = $User.employeeNumber
$Department     = $User.department
$Title          = $User.title
$Office         = $User.office
$Address        = $User.address
$City           = $User.city
$State          = $User.state
$PostalCode     = $User.postalCode
$Company        = $User.company
$Telephone      = $User.telephone
$Mobile         = $User.mobile
$Fax            = $User.fax
$Custom1        = $User.custom1
$Custom2        = $User.custom2
$Custom3        = $User.custom3
$Custom4        = $User.custom4

Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" `
    -SearchBase "OU=Logins,DC=domain,DC=com" |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{ `
    employeeNumber=$EmployeeNumber;
    department=$Department;
    title=$Title;
    Office=$office;
    streetAddress=$Address;
    l=$City;
    st=$State;
    postalCode=$PostalCode;
    company=$Company;
    telephoneNumber=$telephone;
    mobile=$cell;
    facsimileTelephoneNumber=$Fax;
    ExtensionAttribute1=($user.custom1);
    ExtensionAttribute2=($user.custom2);
    ExtensionAttribute3=($user.custom3);
    ExtensionAttribute4=($user.custom4)
                    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some of the errors you're receiving?

Comment: I know it looks bad to have "set-aduser" twice, but I can't find any way to include the extension attributes in with the first group of attributes.  While I can use "Set-ADUser -EmployeeNumber", for the extension attributes, I seem to have to use "Set-ADUser -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute1.....".   Is there a better way to do that specifically?

Comment: Hrm... I suspect that any attribute may be changed using `-Replace [hashtable]` syntax, even if a cmdlet parameter is also provided for the attribute. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps) contains an example that does this with the Title attribute: `Set-ADUser -Identity GlenJohn -Replace @{title="director";mail="glenjohn@fabrikam.com"}`.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to include "Replace" for the extension attributes in the same Set-ADUser as the rest of the properties.  That's ok though, I can just keep it as two separate ones.  My problem now is getting errors due to blanks in the CSV, which I'd like it to skip and keep going.

Comment: I was unclear. My suggestion is to remove all the `-PropertyName` arguments from the `Set-ADUser` and move them into the hashtable passed to `-Remove`.

Comment: I've updated my original script to what I'm using now.  I can't seem to get past this error:  `Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what @veefu suggests, and would like to build off that. To start with, you have different columns in your CSV as to what `Set-ADUser` is expecting. To work around this I would suggest creating a property map hashtable.

```
$PropMap = @{
    EmployeeNumber='EmployeeNumber'
    Department='Department'
    Title='Title'
    office='Office'
    Address='StreetAddress'
    City='City'
    State='State'
    PostalCode='PostalCode'
    Company='Company'
    telephone='OfficePhone'
    cell='Mobile'
    Fax='Fax'
    custom1='ExtensionAttribute1'
    custom2='ExtensionAttribute2'
    custom3='ExtensionAttribute3'
    custom4='ExtensionAttribute4'
}
```

Then you want to find out what the valid parameters for `Set-ADUser` are to determine if a given column should be applied as a parameter, or be fed to the `-Replace` parameter.

```
#Find the valid parameters for the Set-ADUser cmdlet (only strings, to avoid complex objects and switches, and no common parameters)
$ValidParams = Get-Command Set-ADUser -ShowCommandInfo |% ParameterSets |% Parameters |?{$_.ParameterType.FullName -match 'String' -and $_.Name -notin [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters} |Select -Expand Name -Unique
```

Then you import the CSV and loop through the users. For each user you find what properties they have filled in on the spreadsheet, see if it is a parameter for the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet, and build a hashtable to splat to the cmdlet.

```
#Import the list of users and updates
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Employees.csv

#Loop through users
ForEach($User in $Users){
    #Set an empty hashtable for what this user needs to have updated
    $UserParams = @{}
    #Find the properties for this user that have values
    $UserProps = $User.PSObject.Properties.Name |?{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($User.$_)}
    #If it has a parameter in Set-ADUser add it to $UserParams
    $UserProps |?{($ParamName=If($_ -in $PropMap.Keys){$PropMap[$_]}Else{$_}) -in $ValidParams} |%{$UserParams.Add($ParamName,$User.$_)}
    #If it doesn't have a valid parameter build a hashtable for the -Replace parameter, and add that to $UserParams
    $UserProps |?{($ParamName=If($_ -in $PropMap.Keys){$PropMap[$_]}Else{$_}) -notin $ValidParams} |% -Begin {$ToReplace = $_} -Process {$ToReplace.Add($ParamName,$User.$_)} -End {$UserParams.Add('Replace',$ToReplace)}
```

Here I added a little `Try/Catch` to let you know if it failed to find or update any of the users, and if it failed to find them, or failed to update them, and gives the error. I used the shortened `-ea` instead of `-ErrorAction` out of habit.

```
    #Try to find the user, and apply the updates
    Try{
        Get-AdUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -ea Stop | Set-ADUser @UserParams -ea Stop
    }Catch{
        #If the Get-ADUser or Set-ADUser cmdlets failed throw a warning with the user's EmployeeID for investigation

        #Determine if it was Get-ADUser or Set-ADUser that failed, to see if we couldn't find the user or couldn't update the user
        $WarningMessage = If($_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand -eq 'Get-ADUser'){'find'}else{'update'}
        Write-Warning "Unable to $WarningMessage user with EmployeeID (actual error follows): $($User.EmployeeID)"
        Write-Warning "$_`n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your input, much appreciated!  

@TheMadTechnician I'm getting and error on this line:  

    `$ValidParams = Get-Command Set-ADUser -ShowCommandInfo |% ParameterSets |% Parameters |?{$_.ParameterType.FullName -match 'String' -and $_.Name -notin [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters} |Select -Expand Name -Unique`

The error is: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.

I'm not sure where it's looking for a value though.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue. Try running `Update-Help -Module ActiveDirectory -Force` or run the line in parts. Do you get anything for `[System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters`? or `Get-Command Set-ADUser -ShowCommandInfo |% ParameterSets |% Parameters`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few comments:

```
# -3. No parameters to the script and hard-coded path to the input CSV
#     This makes the script harder for others to reuse
# -2. No error handling
#     if an employee in the CSV doesn't exist in AD, for instance,
#     you might want to know about it.
# -1. Rigid requirements for the CSV file
#     What happens if one of the columns is missing? 
#     Would it be worthwhile to add flexibility logic, so 
#     so the script could handle CSVs containing fewer columns of
#     modification?

$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\Employees.csv
# 0. Style - use more vertical space in your code for better readability

foreach ($user in $users) {
# 1. Eliminate duplicate Get-ADUser calls
Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" `
        -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
# 2. Eliminate '-properties *': your script doesn't read 
#    current user property values, so why retrieve them?

# 3. Consider eliminating multiple calls to Set-ADUser
#    All modifications can probably be done in a single
#    Set-ADUser -Replace $Properties
#    call. You'd need to reorganize the modifications into
#    a single hashtable.

    Set-ADUser -EmployeeNumber $($user."EmployeeNumber") `
        -Department $($user."Department") `
        -Title $($user."Title") `
        -Office $($user."office") `
        -StreetAddress $($user."Address") `
        -City $($user."City") `
        -State $($user."State") `
        -PostalCode $($user."PostalCode") `
        -Company $($user."Company") `
        -OfficePhone $($user."telephone") `
        -Mobile $($user."cell") `
        -Fax $($user."Fax")

Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{
            ExtensionAttribute1=($user.custom1) 
            ExtensionAttribute2=($user.custom2)
            ExtensionAttribute3=($user.custom3)
            ExtensionAttribute4=($user.custom4)
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!